# Android Project using Android Support libraries crash, when a dependant library uses AndroidX library

Tags: android

The project uses Android support libraries such as v4, v7, etc., And a dependant library uses AndroidX dependencies. And the app crashes when the dependant library uses the AndroidX class.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/content/ContextCompat;

Comment: Migrate to androidx: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate

Comment: migrate old project to androidx use new material themes and add other dependencies

Comment: Yes, migration is an easy solution, but why does it crash? Is AndroidX not compatible with support libraries?

Comment: AndroidX contains support librairies. So you have conflicts with both librairies.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all the support libraries to androidX and in every class and xml file convert the imports and views to androidX.